# Three-level Group using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that lists classes under a degree program. I have created a XSLT (with help) that successfully creates groups of classes under the degree name. But the client wants a third level that identifies elective and non-elective classes. The elective field is listed with the data "Y" if it is an elective and "N" if is not, or otherwise a "program requirement".

I need to add another level to the XSLT that groups classes under a title "Program Requirement" if it has an "N" in the element `<FlagElectives1>`.

I think I need to create another key based on this element, right, and then create a template that creates a xsl:text title that says either: "Program Requirement" or "Program Elective" but I am stuck. I've never done three-level grouping before.

Here's my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- DWXMLSource="STX049 Catalog parsed.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <CrystalReport>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </CrystalReport>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:key name="degrees-by-title" match="CrystalReport/Group/Group/Group/Details" use="Section/ICCB1" />

  <xsl:template match="CrystalReport/Group/Group/Group">

    <Degree>
      <xsl:for-each select="Details[count(. | key('degrees-by-title', Section/ICCB1)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="Section/ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
        <department>
          <Degreetitle>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/ACPGDEGREE1" />
          </Degreetitle>
          <Certtitle>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/CCD11" />
          </Certtitle>
          <DegreeDesc>
            <xsl:value-of select="Section/ACPGCOMMENTS1"/>
          </DegreeDesc>
          <ICCBcode>
            <xsl:value-of select="Section/ICCB1"/>
          </ICCBcode>
          <ProgramID>
            <xsl:value-of select="Section/ACADPROGRAMSID1"/>
          </ProgramID>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('degrees-by-title', Section/ICCB1)">
            <xsl:sort select="Section/FlagElectives1" order="ascending" />
            <xsl:sort select="Section/DEPARTMENT11" />
            <xsl:sort select="Section/CRSNO1" />

            <Details>
              <class>
                <deptname>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Section/DEPARTMENT11"/>
                </deptname>
                <courseno>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSNO1"/>
                </courseno>
                <classname>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSTITLE1"/>
                </classname>
                <classcredit>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSMINCRED1"/>
                </classcredit>
                <Elective>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Section/FlagElectives1" />
                </Elective>
              </class>
            </Details>

          </xsl:for-each>
        </department>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Degree>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section/ACPGDEGREE1[child::node()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> DEGREE</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section/CCD11[child::node()]">
    <xsl:text> CERTIFICATE</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the structure of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CrystalReport>
  <Group Level="1">
    <Group Level="2">
      <Group Level="3">
        <Details>
          <Section>
            <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
            <CCD11/>
            <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
            <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
            <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
            <CRSNO1>1110</CRSNO1>
            <ACRBPRINTEDSPEC1/>
            <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>2</CRSMINCRED1>
            <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Using Computers: An Introduction</CRSTITLE1>
            <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
            <CRSSUBJECT1>CIS</CRSSUBJECT1>
            <ACRBLABEL1>CIS REQUIREMENT</ACRBLABEL1>
            <CRSMAXCRED1/>
            <FlagElectives1>N</FlagElectives1>
          </Section>
        </Details>
        <Details>
          <Section>
            <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
            <CCD11/>
            <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
            <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
            <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
            <CRSNO1>1150</CRSNO1>
            <ACRBPRINTEDSPEC1/>
            <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>3</CRSMINCRED1>
            <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Intro to Computer</CRSTITLE1>
            <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
            <CRSSUBJECT1>CIS</CRSSUBJECT1>
            <ACRBLABEL1>CIS</ACRBLABEL1>
            <CRSMAXCRED1/>
            <FlagElectives1>Y</FlagElectives1>
          </Section>
        </Details>
      </Group>
    </Group>
  </Group>
</CrystalReport>
```

The first level of grouping should be based on the element `<DEPARTMENT11>`. The title of the various degrees and certificates is found in the field `<ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>` 
The second level unique field in all this is `<ACADPROGRAMSID1>`

Here is the desired output:

```
<CrystalReport>
 <Degrees>

 <!--group and repeat "Degrees" for-each based on element ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1-->

 <areaofstudy>Accounting</areaofstudy>
 <Degree>
 <department>

 <!--group and repeat "department" for-each based on element ICCB1-->

  <Degreetitle>AAS DEGREE</Degreetitle>
  <Certtitle />
  <DegreeDesc>The Accounting program</DegreeDesc>
  <ICCBcode>3203</ICCBcode>
  <ProgramID>ACCOU.AAS</ProgramID>

 <!--group and repeat "Details" for-each based on element ACADPROGRAMSID1 under titles "Program Requirement" or "Program Elective" based on element "FlagElectives1"-->

  <h1>Program Requirements</h1>
  <Details>
    <class>
      <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
      <courseno>1150</courseno>
      <classname>Intro to Computer</classname>
      <classcredit>3</classcredit>
      <Elective>N</Elective>
    </class>
  </Details>
  <h1>Program Electives</h1>
  <Details>
    <class>
      <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
      <courseno>1110</courseno>
      <classname>Using Computers: An Introduction</classname>
      <classcredit>2</classcredit>
      <Elective>Y</Elective>
    </class>
  </Details>
 </department>
 </Degree>
 <Degree>
 <department>
  <Degreetitle>AAS DEGREE</Degreetitle>
  <Certtitle />
  <DegreeDesc>The Accounting program</DegreeDesc>
  <ICCBcode>3203</ICCBcode>
  <ProgramID>ACCOU.AAS</ProgramID>
  <h1>Program Requirements</h1>
  <Details>
    <class>
      <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
      <courseno>1150</courseno>
      <classname>Intro to Computer</classname>
      <classcredit>3</classcredit>
      <Elective>Y</Elective>
    </class>
  </Details>
  <h1>Program Electives</h1>
  <Details>
    <class>
      <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
      <courseno>1110</courseno>
      <classname>Using Computers: An Introduction</classname>
      <classcredit>2</classcredit>
      <Elective>N</Elective>
    </class>
  </Details>
</department>
</Degree>
</Degrees>
</CrystalReport>
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I see you've opened a separate question for the follow-up question. Did my answer here or in the other question I answered (about namespaces) help you? If so, would you kindly mark them as answers?

Comment: Did you update the answer to the same code on the other question? I will mark it as the answer if you do. I opened a second question because some people don't allow multiple steps in questions. One question -> one answer. But the updated XSLT is closer to the final solution.

Comment: Updated now, and yes, I think it is a good idea to open new questions rather than having having one original question drag out with numerous new requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of cleanup on your XSLT.  Any time you have a `for-each` nested inside a `for-each`, that's a good sign that your XSLT needs some refactoring. I think I've understood what you mean by grouping the courses by whether they are electives or not (though you haven't indicated how you want to represent that), so what I came up with is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- DWXMLSource="STX049 Catalog parsed.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:variable name="allSections" 
                select="/CrystalReport/Group/Group/Group/Details/Section" />

  <xsl:key name="kArea" match="Section" use="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1"/>
  <xsl:key name="kDegree" match="Section" 
           use="concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1)" />
  <xsl:key name="kDepartment" match="Section" 
           use="concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1, '+', ICCB1)" />

  <xsl:variable name="degreeFirsts"
           select="$allSections[generate-id() = 
             generate-id(key('kDegree', 
                concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1))[1])]" />
  <xsl:variable name="deptFirsts"
             select="$allSections[generate-id() = 
               generate-id(key('kDepartment',
                concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1, '+', ICCB1))[1])]" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CrystalReport>
      <Degrees>
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="$allSections[generate-id() = 
                 generate-id(key('kArea', ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1)[1])]"
          mode="group"/>
      </Degrees>
    </CrystalReport>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="area" select="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1" />
    <areaofstudy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$area"/>
    </areaofstudy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$degreeFirsts[ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1 = $area]" 
                         mode="degree"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="degree">
    <xsl:variable name="area" select="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1" />
    <xsl:variable name="degree" select="ACPGDEGREE1" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <Degree>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="$deptFirsts[ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1 = $area and ACPGDEGREE1 = $degree]"
        mode="department">
        <xsl:sort select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Degree>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="department">
    <department>
      <Degreetitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGDEGREE1" />
      </Degreetitle>
      <Certtitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CCD11" />
      </Certtitle>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <DegreeDesc>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGCOMMENTS1" />
      </DegreeDesc>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;ICCB Code</xsl:text>
      <ICCBcode>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ICCB1" />
      </ICCBcode>
      <xsl:text> | Field of Study Code: </xsl:text>
      <ProgramID>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
      </ProgramID>
      <xsl:variable name="courses" 
              select="key('kDepartment', 
                   concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1, '+', ICCB1))" />

      <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
        <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'N']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Requirements'" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
        <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'Y']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Electives'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </department>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CourseGroup">
    <xsl:param name="courses" />
    <xsl:param name="title" />

    <xsl:if test="$courses">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$courses">
        <xsl:sort select="FlagElectives1" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:sort select="DEPARTMENT11" />
        <xsl:sort select="CRSNO1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <Details>
      <class>
        <deptname>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="DEPARTMENT11" />
        </deptname>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
        <courseno>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSNO1" />
        </courseno>
        <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
        <classname>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSTITLE1" />
        </classname>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
        <classcredit>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1" />
        </classcredit>
      </class>
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ACPGDEGREE1/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' DEGREE')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CCD11/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' CERTIFICATE')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The elective grouping is achieved through the `call-template` items, that select courses by whether or not they are electives:

```
  <xsl:variable name="courses" 
                select="key('degrees-by-title', ICCB1)" />
  <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
    <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'Y']" />
    <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Requirements'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
```

When run on your sample input, this XSLT produces:

```
<CrystalReport>
  <Degree>
    <department>
      <Degreetitle>AAS DEGREE</Degreetitle>
      <Certtitle />
      <DegreeDesc>The Accounting program</DegreeDesc>
      <ICCBcode>3203</ICCBcode>
      <ProgramID>ACCOU.AAS</ProgramID>
      <h1>Program Requirements</h1>
      <Details>
        <class>
          <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
          <courseno>1150</courseno>
          <classname>Intro to Computer</classname>
          <classcredit>3</classcredit>
          <Elective>Y</Elective>
        </class>
      </Details>
      <h1>Program Electives</h1>
      <Details>
        <class>
          <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
          <courseno>1110</courseno>
          <classname>Using Computers: An Introduction</classname>
          <classcredit>2</classcredit>
          <Elective>N</Elective>
        </class>
      </Details>
    </department>
  </Degree>
</CrystalReport>
```

Note the `h1` elements noting the start of the requirement and elective groups.  If you would like this represented some other way, please clarify that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally confused now. I've never used this method before. Using this stylesheet I lose all my existing tagnames. Your stylesheet gives me data, but doesn't return the tags for many of the items.

When I run it on the data, I get <class>ACCOU2200Income Tax Return Preparation3Y</class>

instead of: 

<class><deptname>ACCOU</deptname><courseno>2200</courseno><classname>Income Tax Return Preparation</classname><classcredit>3</classcredit><Elective>Y</Elective></class>

How do I bring back the tagnames in the result? I also want to use some <xsl:text> elements. Do I build more templates?

Comment: Are you using all of my XSLT on your input, or just some of it? I made a modification to make the XSLT more succinct by doing a lookup of old element names-> new element names, but this uses the `document()` function, and it's possible that your XSLT processor has a restriction on this function. Could you tell me what processor you're using?

Comment: I believe I am using all of your XSLT shown in posting. I see 97 lines of code. I am running it through Adobe Dreamweaver and Safari.

Comment: That's odd.  It seems to work fine in FireFox (I don't have Dreamweaver or Safari).  I've modified it to use a more straightforward approach.  Could you give it a try?  Also, could you answer my question about what the result XML should look like?

Comment: I ran the XML through Oxygen and it provided the final XML as in your sample above. Do you have an idea why Dreamweaver and Safari failed to process the XML? I did get a message from another program that XSL was missing a required attribute: "document() URI"

Comment: The `document()` function usually takes a file path as its parameter, but if passed a blank string, it can be used to dynamically access the XSLT itself.  I guess there are XSLT processors that don't support that behavior.  At any rate, my updated XSLT should be more processor-friendly.  Could you give it a try and let me know if you would like the output arranged differently?

Comment: I tried the latest version and it still drops all the internal tags when I parse from Dreamweaver to Safari or Firefox. It works fine in Oxygen, so Dreamweaver is probably using an older parser. Is this a XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 function?

Comment: As for my extra spacing and text, I've figured out how to add the text I need within this stylesheet. I'm actually importing the XML into a print document and need to add line breaks and boilerplate text. Too bad I can't get Dreamweaver to work with this.

Comment: Both this and the previous version should be 1.0 compliant, and I really don't understand why the tags would be dropped in this one, since I'm producing the individual field values pretty much the same way your ordinary transform did. Dreamweaver sounds like it has some XSLT compliance issues. Could you post the current Dreamweave output to a place like Pastebin?

Comment: Could this stylesheet be used to add up the course credits for the program requirements?

Comment: FYI, using the nested function that I posted works fine in Dreamweaver. But I'm also having the "missing document() URL" attribute error when I try using the XSLT while I'm importing the XML into Adobe InDesign. Looks like both Adobe programs have the same issues with your XSLT. I'll see if someone at Adobe knows what's wrong and let you know if I ever get an answer.

Comment: Yes, using your latest. As I said, it works fine in Oxygen. It's only the Adobe programs that have this issue. I'd like to know why, because it puts a kink in my workflow. Normally, I just use Dreamweaver and I'm done. Now, I've got to add Oxygen to the mix too.

Comment: The new XSLT that I pasted doesn't use the `document()` function at all, and I'd find it incomprehensible if this newer one still produced the values without their surrounding elements.  Could you double-check that you're using the latest version of the XSLT that I provided, and that the old one isn't being reused somehow?  You could try inserting some random text inside one of the templates and see if it's output or not.  It should be possible to sum up course credits (and please tell me how this should be represented in the output), but I'm off to bed for now (it's 5am here).  More tomorrow.

Comment: Ooops. Sorry, didn't see that you edited it again. This version works in Dreamweaver now. Can you see why it should work now? Do you have a specific question I can ask Adobe as to why the last design didn't work? In each case, it was only Adobe's products that didn't create the XML properly.

Comment: My last edit was 3 hours ago, right around when I said, "I've modified it to use a more straightforward approach. Could you give it a try?" Sounds like you were using the previous one this whole time which would explain the disconnect in our conversation. The difference between the newer one and the older one is that the older one used the `document()` function with an empty string as its parameter: `select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'renameItemsList']/item"`. This is perhaps not a very common practice, but it is very useful for dynamically accessing the content of the XSLT itself.

Comment: The error message you provided seemed to be referring precisely to this use of `document()` with an empty string argument. The new version doesn't use the `document()` function at all.

Comment: Hey you were supposed to be in bed?!? Yes, the new version works.

But I forgot that I needed to add the <areaofstudy> title to each main grouping of degrees. It should be the top level title, such as Architecture, Art, or Computer Information Services (CIS) so that Level 1 is the title <areaofstudy> Level II would be the Degree/Certificate title and description, Level III would be the Requirements or Electives groupings. How do you add the <areaofstudy> title to each group?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you want the result XML to look like instead of just describing it?

Comment: I modified my post to show the desired output using the XSLT.